# How to check if FlowLayout overflow?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, flowlayout

In `FlowLayout` if there is no space for components, some of them moving to the next line. Is there way to check if layout overflowed programmatically?

Comment: I guess you should think about to use another layout because this is how the FlowLayout works.

Comment: What exactly do you intend to do if the layout does overflow?  (BTW - Put the container with `FlowLayout` in a scroll pane that specifies no horizontal scroll bar and vertical scroll bar as needed, and it is taken care of automatically.)

Comment: i have some jbuttons on that panel. if some buttons goes to the second line, i will hide the button's text and show only icons. So i need to know if there is any buttons on second line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ChangeListener` for JScrollPane

```
final JScrollPane jPane = new JScrollPane(yourPanel);
jPane.getViewport().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

    public void stateChange(ChangeEvent e) {

        //if that is true, it means panel overflowed
        if(jPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().isShowing()) {

        }
    }

})
```

Comment: Can we do it without `JScrollPane`?

Comment: I don't know any other way.

Comment: I did it, but not with ChangeListener. I added my panel to a JScrollPane and then override my main panel's setPrefferedSize method. So i am listening scroll changes from setPrefferedSize method.